# Fastest way to change non 0 to -1 w/o conditionals?

Tags: numbers

Without using conditionals (if, loops, ?:) what is the fastest way (least amount of cycles) to transform a non 0 number (1, -1, 123) to all bits set (-1 or highest unsigned number)?

The bitsize is known. The solution should work on 32 and 64bit numbers.

Comment: What language are we talking about?

Comment: Do you mean equivalent of `if(x == n) x = -1;`?

Comment: If you really want to know which uses the "least amount of cycles", you would also need to know on what processor, of course.

Comment: And on today's processor, "how many cycles" something takes on average in a given context is essentially something you need to measure empirically.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
foo(int j)
{
    return ((~j + 1) | (-1 & j)) >> ((sizeof(char *) * 8) - 1);
}

int
main()
{
    int r, j;

    j = 0;
    r = foo(j);
    printf("j = %d, r = %d\n", j, r);

    j = -1;
    r = foo(j);
    printf("j = %d, r = %d\n", j, r);

    j = 123;
    r = foo(j);
    printf("j = %d, r = %d\n", j, r);

    return(0);
}
```

running it results in

```
j = 0, r = 0
j = -1, r = -1
j = 123, r = -1
```

Comment: Obviously, this doesn't guarantee you that it will be the solution using the least number of clock cycles on a given machine, but it's a branchless solution and I guess that's what the OP was getting at-- as I say, what sequence of operations used fewer cycles would depend on the processor (and potentially, nowadays, on surrounding context, other threads competing for the CPU at a given moment-- it's a bit of a non-question when taken at its most literal).

Comment: @NeilCoffey: I didn't mean literally the least. There could be a non mainstream hardware that does it fast or really really slow. This should be fast on most/all hardware. Its better then one idea i had that took more then N operations where N is the amount of bits

Comment: The above code doesn't quite give the required result, but you can save it (or indeed anything that returns 0 vs negative numbers) by right-shifting the result by 31 places. In other words, change the formula to: ((~j + 1) | (-1 & j)) >> 31.

Comment: But of course if this is for real life and not just a homework question, you should see if in reality it gives any tangible benefit over (x != 0) ? -1 : 0.

Comment: I have incorporated @Neil Coffey's idea and this should now work on both, 64 bit as well as 32 bit machines. Neil -- that was a good one.

Answer (score 0):

In C, given a non-zero number `n`, `!n` should yield 0, and since `~0` should give the all-ones pattern, `~!n` would, on most systems turn any non-zero number to -1. I think that what it does with 0, though is implementation-defined - `!0` is frequently `1`, but I don't recall if that's guaranteed. C++ should be similar, although the intricacies of type conversions between an `int` `n` to the `bool` result of `!n` and back to an `int` for the `~` operator might be a little hard to follow, and have some subtle details to consider...

If in doubt, try it on your compiler (or all compilers you care about - it's not a particularly difficult test case to write).

Comment: The only thing is you have less guarantee that ! will be compiled to a branchless implementation than the standard bitwise operators. (I'm guessing that the purpose of "avoiding conditionals" would usually be to avoid branches.)